# @KafkaListener not receives records

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Cannot determine, what is wrong with my kafka listener configuration. Initialy, I have non-empty kafka topic named *"transactions"* with several records (I can see it in KafkaTool). 
This is application.yml:

```
spring:
  ###
  #   Kafka Settings
  ###
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      key-deserializer: com.panbet.externalbet.history.report.support.ReportsBetKeyJsonDeserializer
      value-deserializer: com.panbet.externalbet.history.report.support.ReportsBetJsonDeserializer
      group-id: external.history.group
```

Here is Java config file:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig
{
    private final KafkaProperties properties;


    public KafkaConfig(KafkaProperties properties)
    {
        this.properties = properties;
    }


    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<ReportsBetKeyDto, ReportsBetDto> kafkaConsumerFactory()
    {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(properties.buildConsumerProperties());
    }


    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<ReportsBetKeyDto, ReportsBetDto> kafkaListenerContainerFactory()
    {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<ReportsBetKeyDto, ReportsBetDto> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

My kafka listener looks like (listener for topic "transactions" that was mentioned previously):

```
@Component
public class ReportsConsumer
{
    @KafkaListener(topics = { "transactions" })
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<ReportsBetKeyDto, ReportsBetDto> record)
    {
        System.out.println(record);
    }
}
```

I expect: when application starts, I'll catch debudder inside ReportsConsumer.listen method. But unfurtunately, nothing happens. Listened doesn't connects to kafka topic. What can be wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any warning or errors in log?

Comment: is your `KafkaProperties` annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` and with corresponding prefix specified?

Comment: KafkaProperties are took from application.yml in kafka: consumer: bootstrap-servers: etc.

Comment: Only this warn: WARN 26572 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=1m13s632ms528µs231ns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, new consumers start consuming from the end of the topic.

Set `spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest`

I also recommend `spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false` so that the container manages the offsets.